# Express static with Middleware require login

Tags: node.js, express

I created two uploads folder are public and private. Public folder does not require auth but private folder will require a middleware to access;

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads/public/'));
app.use('/uploads', require('./admin/routers/api/accessPrivate'), express.static('uploads/private/'));
```

And here is my `accessPrivate`

```
const userPermission = require("../../middleware/permission");
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');

const accessMedia = async ( req, res, next) => {
  await auth(req, res, next); 
  next();
};

module.exports = accessMedia;
```

But it shows error: "No token". It means that there is no `req` header sent to server; Can you tell me how to do?

Thank you so much;

Answer (score 1):

Define a general middleware for all `uploads` requests. Check the user's permission.

```
app.use('/uploads', async (req, res, next) => {

  let hasAccess = await auth(req, res, next);
  if (hasAccess) {
    app.use(express.static('uploads/private/'));
  }
  else {
    app.use(express.static('uploads/public/'));
  }
  next();
});

// your routes

app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
  let target = 'index.html';

  if (req.baseUrl && req.baseUrl != '/') {
    target = req.baseUrl;
  }
  if(req.user) {
    root = 'uploads/private/';
  }
  else {
    root = 'uploads/public/';
  }
  res.sendFile(target, { root: root })
});
```

Also you should change the `auth` implementation.

Comment: thank you for your answer but as your suggestion. It is not a middleware, even if you put 
`express.static('uploads/public/');` inside app.use, it also not work.

Comment: It does not serve static files?? @HaiTien

Comment: Hi Saeed. As your method, It returns "cannot get file". It looks like get method, not serving static file.

Comment: Can you try my updated answer? It is just for getting files in client side, not the target path of uploaded files. @HaiTien

Comment: thank you for your updates. Can you tell me target is?

Comment: I add missing target, This code is part of my simple express server, Check whole code in [here](https://github.com/Saeed-Ataee/Express-server) @HaiTien